# App crash on large string in TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display 4 long pieces of text (about 250 chars long each) inside a TextView separated by a few images on android. This is inside a fragment which is placed in a scrollView on the Host activity to make it scrollable.

But it throws

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

I was surprised to see that the app went out of memory by this because the only thing it has to do is display 250 characters and apply word wrap to it. So after googling it I set android:largeHeap to true to see what would happen. The application does load the text but it uses a lot of CPU resources and makes the UI come to a snail phase.

So I am wondering: what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for reading.

Here is the complete crash:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 69120012 byte
>   allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>                                                                                at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2730)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2635)
>                                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:152)
>                                                                                at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:140)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                                                                                at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                at
>   nl.evhb.evhbmijnopbrengst.FragmentCoTwoInformation.onCreateView(FragmentCoTwoInformation.java:25)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Kindly paste your crash log.

Comment: can you post your fragments code here to give us more insight??

Comment: When your text is too much long you should chunk it in small pieces And display it as a `ListView`.

Comment: 250 characters is not a lot. I suspect you have problems with images rather than textviews. Post your code and logcat

Comment: I have added a logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry but after looking into the log again I realized that I imported the images on full 1080p resolution which is too much to process for android.graphics.BitmapFactory and that is why it goes out of memory.

I made the images to a mobile friendly size and it worked fine.

Comment: I already did that as I said in my first post but it makes everything very slow and uses way too much resources.Downscaling the images worked fine without losing detail anyway.

Comment: 1080pix width / height is not really big for android. Sizing down to what you need is always an good idea.

Comment: @Ghostcat This is quite an old question but you are right. Marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryError`enter code here` error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.
Try it...

```
  <application
.......................
............
         android:largeHeap="true"
        >
```